# Hash CSS filename without webpack

Tags: html, css, webpack, sass

Am building minimal scss boilerplate. Is there way to hash output css filename and inject that filename to index.html. Am avoiding webpack to keep build process as simple as possible. Here is my current package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "scss-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "sass --watch --update --style=expanded assets/scss:assets/css",
    "build": "sass --no-source-map --style=compressed assets/scss:assets/css"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.63.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SASS has no features for generating output with unique file names nor for modifying HTML documents.

You need an additional tool (such as webpack, which you've rejected).

Comment: The reason to avoid webpack is to create simple frontend workflow. My clients sometimes use the html pages I created with php. I use webpack to bundle all my assets.  Things work good initially, they just copy the output folder rename html to php and start their php work. Problem arises when it's time to update frontend, since html files have been renamed to php my webpack config no longer works. I have been seraching for a smooth workflow between webpack, php and sass but not able to find any.